# Use field from most recent record based on one-to-many relationship - Filemaker Pro 11

Tags: filemaker

I am fairly new to Filemaker, and I am trying to figure out how to so something that I have done several times using SQL. I have a database with two tables. One is a user storage table (Users - UserID, UserName, UserAddress, EdExpires), and the other stores educational interactions (UserEd - EdID, UserID, EdType, EdDate), and the tables are joined in a one-to-many relationship based on Users::UserID - UserEd::UserID. What I am trying to do, is in the Users table create a calculated field (EdExpires) which will display an expiration date for thier current education. Essentially, this would be UserEd::EdDate + 3 years. The problem, is that over time, there will be multiple UserEd Entried for each user.

I know how to display the UserEd::EdDate, and even add three years to it using a calculated field (User::EdExpires = UserEd:EdDate + (365*3)). But how can I specify that UserEd:EdDate be the most recent record? Do I need to create a new query sorted by date? Is there a way within the calculation to specify that the most recent record from UserEd be used?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I simply needed to use the MAX() function to return the most recent date...

```
MAX(UserEd:EdDate) + (365 * 3)
```